# How to send continuous HTTP streaming data to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

We have a system (Example System A) that sends time series data via HTTP.

I would now like to introduce Apache Kafka into the system.

The idea for me would be to have a Kafka server running, where System A as soon as receiving time series messages, publishes this message to the Apache Kafka server.

Here, I have a doubt, how to publish time series data which is coiming through HTTP protocal?

here is a example.

i have below url to collect the data:

http://ipaddress:portno/HttpPush/Track?event

receiving following straming data

2017-08-17 00:00:21  INFO: ?data=$Sensor,x8,86832364748057,20170816235919,13,1,1,5|2,0,7,20170816235854,0,0,0,0,128,0,4095|3,0,10,20170816235854,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00|2,0,7,20170816235859,0,0,0,0,128,0,4095

Note : i am receving 20kps data

could anyone please help me with sample kafka producer API for this example.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kafka REST Proxy](http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/intro.html) may be useful here. The source system could stream its data directly to Kafka over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the data from the URL into String and paas that data into a method that publishes the data to kafka.
1st, initialize a producer with producer properties (e.g, refer below code snippet)

```
producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(KafkaConfiguration.producerProperties);
            logger.info("JetKafkaProducer{" + this.hashCode() + "} initalised Successfully ,for the topic {" + topic
                    + "}");
            logger.debug("JetKafkaProducer with hash code: {" + this.hashCode() + "}, for the topic{" + topic
                    + "} has producer properties: " + KafkaConfiguration.producerProperties);
```

Now publish the message

```
public void publishMesssage(String data) throws Exception {
    if (getTopic() != null && data != null) {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(this.getTopic(), data);
        producer.send(record); // This publishes message on given topic
        logger.info("Published record to Kafka " + data.toString());
    } else {
        logger.error("Failed to publish record to " + getTopic() + " Data: " + data.toString());
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but here my question is getting the data from URL because it is a streaming data. I have used org.apache.http.HttpResponse class to collect the data but it is working when the response is static but here i am getting the stream of live data like log files . is there anyway to collect the streaming data?

Comment: So you don't have the source code to the streaming server? You will need to create a proxy between your Streaming server and Kafka, so the proxy calls the that publishMessage() method.